# How can I avoid prefixing Symfony form fields?

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to create simple filtering form that uses GET request to show results on page. However symfony adds form name as a prefix to every single field of the form. This produces very ugly URL.

How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments: yes, in Simfony3 method getName() has been removed. In earlier versions you still can use it and still can return empty string from this method. In version > 3 you should use method getBlockPrefix() for the same purposes.

So you code should look like this (version < 3):

```
class DataFormType extends AbstractType
{
    // ...

    public function getName()
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Or like this (version > 3):

```
class DataFormType extends AbstractType
{
    // ...

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it dangerous to use empty name? I haven't looked deep into code, but looks like some registration of forms happens using name provided in that method.

Comment: I'd say that if it was dangerous Symfony team wouldn't let to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can choose the prefix like so :

```
class DataFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'prefix-you-want';
    }
}
```

Comment: `Could not load type "prefix-you-want"`

Comment: According to Symfony docs _The getName() method returns the identifier of this form "type". These identifiers must be unique in the application. Unless you want to override a built-in type, they should be different from the default Symfony types and from any type defined by a third-party bundle installed in your application. Consider prefixing your types with app to avoid identifier collisions._
So this can't definitely be any prefix you want neither it can be empty.

Comment: Actually it might be either empty or set to any value you want. At least in earlier versions (2.3 for example). Technically form name is not necessary because it's your choice how to build form in template: to use prefix or not. I'd suggest not to use Symfony forms at all if it possible (if your logic is quite difficult). I can't say it makes you happier - probably in a way, but sometimes it hurts. Just try to return empty string in getName() method.

Comment: @Alex has the answer.  Don't user Symfony forms if the out of the box solution does not fit your needs.  BTW, getName is removed in 3.0 and replaced with getGroup or something like that.  But if you want short url friendly names then make your own form.